# Derivative of Fourier series

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, fourier-series

Let function $f(t)$ is represented by Fourier series,
$$\frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n\cos{\frac{2n\pi t}{b-a}}+b_n\sin{\frac{2n\pi t}{b-a}}),$$
where $a$ and $b$ are lower and upper boundary,
$$a_0=\frac{2}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}f(t)dt,$$
$$a_n=\frac{2}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}f(t)cos\frac{2n\pi  t}{b-a}dt,$$
$$b_n=\frac{2}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}f(t)sin\frac{2n\pi  t}{b-a}dt.$$

My question is, what conditions must be met so I can find derivative as (term by term)
$$\frac{d}{dt}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n\cos{\frac{2n\pi t}{b-a}}+b_n\sin{\frac{2n\pi t}{b-a}})=\frac{d}{dt}(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\cos{\frac{2n\pi t}{b-a}}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n\sin{\frac{2n\pi t}{b-a}})=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{d}{dt}(a_n\cos{\frac{2n\pi t}{b-a}})+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{d}{dt}(b_n\sin{\frac{2n\pi t}{b-a}})?$$

Answer (score 5):

A sufficient condition for differentiability of the series and commuting of sum and derivative is that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\big(\lvert a_n\rvert+\lvert b_n\rvert\big)<\infty.
$$ 
See: Rudin, *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*, Theorem 7.17, p. 152.

Answer (score 1):

We need the Fourier Series to converge uniformly on the interval $ [A,B] $ (which may be open or closed). Then we can integrate and differentiate the Fourier Series term by term. To check for uniform convergence, we can use the Weierstrass M Test:

If $$ |x| \leq M_n \forall \space t \in I $$

Where $M_n$ is independent of t, and $$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty M_n$$ converges, then $$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty u_k(t)$$ converges uniformly on the interval $I$

Comment: Thanks a lot !!