# Prove $f(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_ne^{inx}$ satisfying $\sum |n||a_n|\leq 1$ is continuously differentiable

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, fourier-series

> Prove that the derivative of a continuous function $f:[0,2\pi]\to\mathbb{C}$ which has the fourier series expansion $f(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_ne^{inx}$ satisfying $\sum |n||a_n|\leq 1$ is continuously differentiable.

My understanding is that for a function $f$ to be continuous on its domain we need to prove that $\lim_{x\to a^+} f(x)=\lim_{x\to a^-} f(x)=\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=f(a)$ for any element $a$ in its domain.

Taking the derivative $f'(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n.in.e^{inx}=g(x)$

For any $a\in[0,2\pi]$
$$
\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=\lim_{x\to a}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n.in.e^{inx}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\lim_{x\to a} a_n.in.e^{inx}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n.in.e^{ina}=g(a)
$$
Thereby proving $f'(x)$ is continuous and therefore continuously differentiable.

Is it sufficient to prove that the function is continuously differentiable ?

Comment: You can't just "take the derivative" as in the second paragraph; you need to **show** that the derivative of the sum is the sum of the derivatives. Similarly in the display, you need to explain how you know that $\lim\sum=\sum\lim$. Both those need justification because it's an _infinite_ series...

Comment: Are you familiar with the Weierstrass M-test and theorems on uniform convergence?

Comment: @MarkViola no I am not.

Comment: It will be worthwhile to do so, especially given your question.

Comment: See [THIS](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1754033/integration-and-differentiation-of-fourier-series).